# Подбор пароля с помощью регулярных выражений

Tags: python, python-3.x, регулярные-выражения

После запуска программы (на Python), даже когда ввожу подходящий пароль, пишет *Password not valid*

```
import re

passRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}')          # Символы допустимые в пароле
myPass = input()                                    # Пароль, который будем проверять
if re.match(passRegex, myPass) is not myPass:
    print('Password not valid')
else:
    print('Valid password')
```

Что делаю не так?

Answer (score 2):

Комманда

```
if re.match(passRegex, myPass) is not myPass:
```

не правильна (к тому же использует `myPass` дважды, что само особе сомнительное).

Замените часть

```
if re.match(passRegex, myPass) is not myPass:
    print('Password not valid')
else:
    print('Valid password')
```

на

```
if re.match(passRegex, myPass):
    print('Valid password')
else:
    print('Password not valid')
```

Заметите, пожалуйста, взаимной обмен тел ветвей `if` и `else`.

Answer (score 2):

Здесь две ошибки, одна в самом коде, другая - в регулярном выражении (или же снова эту ошибку можно исправить с помощью кода):

1. `re.match` возвращает объект совпадения (*match data object*) или, при отсутствии совпадения, `None`. Поэтому `if re.match(passRegex, myPass) is not myPass` неверно, так как всегда верно.
2. `re.match` ищет совпадение только в начале строки. Так как пароль должен состоять из 8 и более букв или цифр, необходимо либо добавить в конце регулярного выраджения знак `$` (конец строки, чтобы требовалось совпадение целой строки), либо - в Python 3.x - можно воспользоваться методом `re.fullmatch`, который требует совпадения целой строки.

Для совместимости с Python 2.x, приведу следующий пример исправленного кода с использованием `re.match`:

```
passRegex = re.compile(r'[a-zA-Z0-9]{8,}$') 
if passRegex.match(myPass):
    print('Пароль верный')
else:
    print('Неверный пароль')
```

Обратите внимание, объект `passRegex` - это уже скомпилированное регулярное выражение, можно использовать метод `match` данного объекта напрямую.

Answer (score 1):

```py
re.match(passRegex, myPass)
```

Эта строка кода возвращает объект не строкового типа, поэтому сравнивать его с Вашим паролем некорректно. Поменяйте условие на

```py
is not None:
```

и местами сообщения.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую

Comment: @VeraSimkina вместо  `if m is not None:`, здесь можно `if m:` писать.